# C# / EntityFramwork. Wrong Double-Value when using Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are using EntityFramework along with MySQL.

We have now noted that the EMF returns wrong values for a Double-Field, when the entity in question is queried through an `Include()`- Statement.

Any Ideas on that? I have no clue, if there is any possibility to take any influence on that - or if it's just a bug?

Database:

[image]

Querying the Product and using `Include()` on the ProductInformation returns a double-value of `71.0`:

[image]

Querying the Product and using lazyloading behaviour on the ProductInformation returns the correct Value of `7.1`:

[image]

Is there any way a missconfiguration could cause this? I'm afraid that this is some sort of general bug, because obviously we are loading a lot of entities containing double values through `Include` - Might affect a lot of stuff without somebody noticing it until now.

---

I've now looked at the generated query. It looks weired, but after all just a bunch of selects, joins and subselects, no special conversion / casting inside the query.

But I also found out, that this query (Include `ProductInformation` before the `ProductGroup_to_AttributeDefinition`) is throwing exceptions (Failed to parse String as Boolean):

```
this.Entity = this.MerpDB.Product             
            .Include("ProductAttribute")
            .Include("ProductGroup")
            .Include("ProductInformation")
            .Include("ProductGroup.ProductGroup_to_AttributeDefinition")
            .Where(x => x.Id == entityId)
            .First();
```

while using this query (ommiting the `ProductGroup_to_AttributeDefinition` at all)

```
this.Entity = this.MerpDB.Product             
            .Include("ProductAttribute")
            .Include("ProductGroup")
            .Include("ProductInformation")
          //.Include("ProductGroup.ProductGroup_to_AttributeDefinition")
            .Where(x => x.Id == entityId)
            .First();
```

works *and* generates the correct double-value for the `ProductInformation`-Entity.

Very, very weired, how can including another entity alter the (value) result s for another entity included? No matter if there might be a design-flaw on the structure that doesn't make any sence at all.

Comment: No clue what might be the issue, but I would perhaps start by calling `ToTraceString()` to compare the generated SQL in both case, to see if there is a difference. Also double check if the table column mapping is correct (i.e. are you specifying the type and precision, and are you getting any compile or runtime warnings regarding these entities).

Comment: @vgru see my update - it generally works, but not in case the `ProductGroup_to_AttributeDefinition` is queryied as well. Don't understand :P